# Expected indented blockPylance

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

```
    from tkinter import CENTER
    global f
    f = 0
    #this t_movie function is used to select movie name
    def t_movie():
    global f
    f = f+1
    print("which movie do you want to watch?")
    print("1,movie 1 ")
    print("2,movie 2 ")
    print("3,movie 3")
    print("4,back")
    movie = int(input("choose your movie: "))
    if movie == 4:
    # in this it goes to center function and from center it goes to movie function and it 
    comes back here and then go to theater
    CENTER()
    theater()
    return 0
    if f == 1:
    theater()
    # this theater function used to select screen
    def theater():
    print("which screen do you want to watch movie: ")
    print("1,SCREEN 1")
    print("2,SCREEN 2")
    print("3,SCREEN 3")
    a = int(input("choose your screen: "))
    ticket = int(input("number of ticket do you want?: "))
    timing(a)
    # this timing function used to select timing for movie
    def timing(a):
    time1 = {
        "1": "10.00-1.00",
        "2": "1.10-4.10",
        "3": "4.20-7.20",
        "4": "7.30-10.30"
    }
    time2 = {
        "1": "10.15-1.15",
        "2": "1.25-4.25",
        "3": "4.35-7.35",
        "4": "7.45-10.45"
    }
    time3 = {
        "1": "10.30-1.30",
        "2": "1.40-4.40",
        "3": "4.50-7.50",
        "4": "8.00-10.45"
    }
    if a == 1:
        print("choose your time:")
        print(time1)
        t = input("select your time:")
        x = time1[t]
        print("successful!, enjoy movie at "+x)
    elif a == 2:
        print("choose your time:")
        print(time2)
        t = input("select your time:")
        x = time2[t]
        print("successful!, enjoy movie at "+x)
    elif a == 3:
        print("choose your time:")
        print(time3)
        t = input("select your time:")
        x = time3[t]
        print("successful!, enjoy movie at "+x)
    return 0
    def movie(theater):
    if theater == 1:
        t_movie()
    elif theater == 2:
        t_movie()
    elif theater == 3:
        t_movie()
    elif theater == 4:
        city()
    else:
        print("wrong choice")
    def center():
    print("which theater do you wish to see movie? ")
    print("1,Inox")
    print("2,Icon")
    print("3,pvp")
    print("4,back")
    a = int(input("choose your option: "))
    movie(a)
    return 0
    # this function is used to select city
    def city():
    print("Hi welcome to movie ticket booking: ")
    print("where you want to watch movie?:")
    print("1,city 1")
    print("2,city 2 ")
    print("3,city 3 ")
    place = int(input("choose your option: "))
    if place == 1:
    center()
    elif place == 2:
    center()
    elif place == 3:
    center()
    else:
    print("wrong choice")
    city() # it calls the function city
```

Comment: You have no indentation here.  Indentation is syntax in Python, and what you have here is all wrong.

Comment: The official python tutorial can help with these basic syntax issues. Especially [First steps towards programming](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming) which introduces python's indentation rules.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code with the indentation fixed.  At least, I think it's fixed,  Your structure is confusing, so it's hard to tell.

```
from tkinter import CENTER
f = 0
#this t_movie function is used to select movie name
def t_movie():
    global f
    f = f+1
    print("which movie do you want to watch?")
    print("1,movie 1 ")
    print("2,movie 2 ")
    print("3,movie 3")
    print("4,back")
    movie = int(input("choose your movie: "))
    if movie == 4:
# in this it goes to center function and from center it goes to movie function and it comes back here and then go to theater
        CENTER()
        theater()
        return 0
    if f == 1:
        theater()

# this theater function used to select screen
def theater():
    print("which screen do you want to watch movie: ")
    print("1,SCREEN 1")
    print("2,SCREEN 2")
    print("3,SCREEN 3")
    a = int(input("choose your screen: "))
    ticket = int(input("number of ticket do you want?: "))
    timing(a)

# this timing function used to select timing for movie
def timing(a):
    time1 = {
        "1": "10.00-1.00",
        "2": "1.10-4.10",
        "3": "4.20-7.20",
        "4": "7.30-10.30"
    }
    time2 = {
        "1": "10.15-1.15",
        "2": "1.25-4.25",
        "3": "4.35-7.35",
        "4": "7.45-10.45"
    }
    time3 = {
        "1": "10.30-1.30",
        "2": "1.40-4.40",
        "3": "4.50-7.50",
        "4": "8.00-10.45"
    }
    if a == 1:
        print("choose your time:")
        print(time1)
        t = input("select your time:")
        x = time1[t]
        print("successful!, enjoy movie at "+x)
    elif a == 2:
        print("choose your time:")
        print(time2)
        t = input("select your time:")
        x = time2[t]
        print("successful!, enjoy movie at "+x)
    elif a == 3:
        print("choose your time:")
        print(time3)
        t = input("select your time:")
        x = time3[t]
        print("successful!, enjoy movie at "+x)
    return 0

def movie(theater):
    if theater == 1:
        t_movie()
    elif theater == 2:
        t_movie()
    elif theater == 3:
        t_movie()
    elif theater == 4:
        city()
    else:
        print("wrong choice")

def center():
    print("which theater do you wish to see movie? ")
    print("1,Inox")
    print("2,Icon")
    print("3,pvp")
    print("4,back")
    a = int(input("choose your option: "))
    movie(a)
    return 0

# this function is used to select city
def city():
    print("Hi welcome to movie ticket booking: ")
    print("where you want to watch movie?:")
    print("1,city 1")
    print("2,city 2 ")
    print("3,city 3 ")
    place = int(input("choose your option: "))
    if place == 1:
        center()
    elif place == 2:
        center()
    elif place == 3:
        center()
    else:
        print("wrong choice")

city() # it calls the function city
```